# Is it possible to retain variable contents when GNU make restarts?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My build system updates makefile includes and then restarts to rescan the dependencies. Is it possible to retain the contents of all or some selected make variables through make restarts?
It would be convenient to store the time when build was started to calculate the elapsed time at different build phases. What's happening is the following:

```
$(if $(MAKE_RESTARTS), $(info $(TEST_VAR)), TEST_VAR=hello)
```

During the second pass, TEST_VAR is undefined. It's forgotten during restart.

Comment: There is no way to preserve environment variables across restarts.  You will have to write the information to a file, then read it back out later.  You can use the value of the `MAKE_RESTARTS` variable to determine whether this is the first instance or a restart.

Answer (score 3):

The assignment can be written to a file and used by the restarted make:

```
$(if $(MAKE_RESTARTS),,$(file >saved.mk,TEST_VAR = hello))
include saved.mk
```